# Passing through data from 2 mongodb objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, routes

I'm creating a blog site and am trying to implement a function so that users can report specific comments. The idea is that the user will click on a 'report' link beneath a specific comment and be taken to a new page which will be pre-populated with both the comment they are reporting and the title of the blog which the comment belongs to.

I have written the following route so far:

```
router.get('/blogs/:blog_id/comments/:comment_id/report', function(req, res) {
// find comment
Comment.findById(req.params.comment_id, function(err, foundComment){
if(err){
  res.redirect('/blogs');
} else {
  res.render('report-comment', {comment: foundComment});
}
});
});
```

This is successfully generating my report comment page and from the report comment page I can then populate the comment using eps <%=comment.text%>. However, I cannot work out in this route how to pass through the blog details that the comment is embedded within. In my report comment form I want to be able to populate the blog title using <%=blog.title%> but where in my route do I pass the blog info through?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `req` object to pass along information from one middleware function to next middleware functions. Also you should specify separate middleware functions for retrieving different data and then finally render it. e.g. You can modify your code something like:

```
router.get('/blogs/:blog_id/comments/:comment_id/report',
  function( req, res, next ){
    // this is first middleware and fetches comment data
    Comment.findById(req.params.comment_id, function(err, foundComment){
      if(err){
        res.redirect('/blogs');
      }else{
        req.comment = foundComment;
        next();
      }
    });//findById()
  },      
  function(req, res, next){
    // this is second middleware that fetches blog data
   Blog.findById(req.params.blog_id, function(err, foundBlog){
     if(err){
       res.redirect('/blogs');
     } else {
       req.blog = foundBlog;
       next();
     }
  });
},
function( req, res ){
  // this is third and final middleware that renders the page
  var pageInfo = {};
  pageInfo.comment = req.comment;
  pageInfo.blog = req.blog;
  res.render("/report-template", pageInfo);
});
```

Now, in your `report-template` file, you can use these variables as `comment` and `blog`.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you that works absolutely perfectly :)